# MySQL query to count sequential occurrences of certain numbers

Tags: mysql

Another "sequential occurrences" MySQL question, but I think it hasn't been asked before.

I have a table that looks like this

```
+----+------+---------------------+------+-----------+--------------+
| id | unit |       datetime      | idle | idlecount | boutduration |
+----+------+---------------------+------+-----------+--------------+
| 1  |  A   | 2009-12-04 08:10:05 |  139 |           |              |
| 2  |  A   | 2009-12-04 08:20:05 |  107 |           |              |
| 3  |  A   | 2009-12-04 08:30:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 4  |  A   | 2009-12-04 08:40:05 |  144 |           |              |
| 5  |  A   | 2009-12-04 08:50:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 6  |  A   | 2009-12-04 09:00:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 7  |  A   | 2009-12-04 09:10:05 |  58  |           |              |
| 8  |  A   | 2009-12-04 09:20:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 9  |  A   | 2009-12-04 09:30:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 10 |  A   | 2009-12-04 09:40:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 11 |  A   | 2009-12-04 09:50:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 12 |  A   | 2009-12-04 10:00:05 |  107 |           |              |
| 13 |  A   | 2009-12-04 10:10:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 14 |  A   | 2009-12-04 10:20:05 |  144 |           |              |
| etc...
```

I need to count the number of sequential occurrences of zeros in column `idle` and determine the duration of each sequence. Single occurrences are irrelevant. So the result should look like this

```
+----+------+---------------------+------+-----------+--------------+
| id | unit |       datetime      | idle | idlecount | boutduration |
+----+------+---------------------+------+-----------+--------------+
| 1  |  A   | 2009-12-04 08:10:05 |  139 |           |              |
| 2  |  A   | 2009-12-04 08:20:05 |  107 |           |              |
| 3  |  A   | 2009-12-04 08:30:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 4  |  A   | 2009-12-04 08:40:05 |  144 |           |              |
| 5  |  A   | 2009-12-04 08:50:05 |  0   |     2     |   00:20:00   |
| 6  |  A   | 2009-12-04 09:00:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 7  |  A   | 2009-12-04 09:10:05 |  58  |           |              |
| 8  |  A   | 2009-12-04 09:20:05 |  0   |     4     |   00:40:00   |
| 9  |  A   | 2009-12-04 09:30:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 10 |  A   | 2009-12-04 09:40:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 11 |  A   | 2009-12-04 09:50:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 12 |  A   | 2009-12-04 10:00:05 |  107 |           |              |
| 13 |  A   | 2009-12-04 10:10:05 |  0   |           |              |
| 14 |  A   | 2009-12-04 10:20:05 |  144 |           |              |
| etc...
```

I assume this requires the use of [flow control statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flow-control-statements.html) but I have never used that before and feel a tad intimidated by the MySQL documentation. Nevertheless I dream of a one-query-solution.

Cheers, Tom

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with correlated subqueries.  The first gets the next non-zero value after each.  The second counts the values in-between.  Here is an example to get the idle count:

```
select t.*,
       (select (case when count(*) > 1 then count(*) end)
        from t t3
        where t3.id >= t.id and
              (t3.id < t.nextNonZeroIdle or nextNonZeroIdle is NULL) and
              t3.idle = 0
       ) as IdleCOunt
from (select t.id, t.unit, t.datetime, t.idle,
             (select id
              from t t2
              where t2.unit = t.unit and
                    t2.id > t.id and
                    t2.idle > 0
              order by id
              limit 1
             ) as nextNonZeroIdle
      from t
     ) t
from t;
```

Comment: Wow, I'm still digesting your answer. But I have a hunch that this query might take hours to iterate through my table. It has around 1.7 million rows... ;)